# How do I configure nginx to serve PDF files?

Tags: nginx, pdf

I am starting with a default installation of nginx. The only modification I've made to my `enabled-sites/default` file is:

```
root /home/ubuntu/www
```

...where I have a web site and a `/pdf` folder that contains my pdf files.

If I click a link to a pdf file, it gets served as text/html and of course looks rather broken in the browser window.

If I add Jeremy's configuration section from http://www.jeremywalworth.com/index.php?q=taxonomy/term/49, then I get 404's for the same pdf file link.

Comment: I got this working by regenerating the PDF; perhaps it was corrupted in some way.

Comment: I had this problem, and I had configured `mime.types` correctly. The problem was that nginx only sets the content-type on files it actually returns. If nginx is just a gateway to (in my case) a django site, the django code is responsible for setting `content-type` correctly

Answer (score 5):

check if the mime.types file has this entry

```
application/pdf                       pdf;
```

and if you include the mime.types file in the http section of your conf

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
...
}
```

Comment: I had already done that. Thanks, though.